# Parse, parseexact string (varchar) from db mysql to datetimepicker in sql query C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime, datetimepicker

I work on the application of winform, which receives data through the selection of dates, through the dateTimePicker1, and displays the data in the datagridview, and after all the data is displayed the application exports these data to the excel. My problem is that I can not figure out how to make a column parser (dmeasurement1 in MySql) and bind it to the datetime peeker and do it all in the sql query.

```
String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime userDate = DateTime.Parse(userInput);

        string query = "SELECT * from EX_S[enter image description here][1]UM WHERE dmeasurement1 between '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.DateParse  + "'";
```

Comment: Learn about SQL Parameterization.

Comment: Use parameters. BUT that SQL is invalid anyway.

Comment: dateTimePicker2.Value.DateParse I insert for example for this question, in fact I tried different solutions to the problem (for example dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString ("dd / MM / yyyy"), and always output in datagridview either nothing or all db). In general, I realized that it is necessary to convert the column varchar to mysql via DateTime.Parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM EX_SUM WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dmeasurement1, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "-") + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "-") + " '"; //yyyy - MM - dd
```

Converts varchar to datetimepicker C #